# Obtaining the phase component of an integer shift using phase only correlation

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, computer-vision, phase

I'm trying to implement a sub-pixel estimation approach for my stereo matching project that I'm working on, by using the proposed method in the following paper "*[Sub-pixel Shift Estimation of Image based on the Least Squares Approximation in Phase Region](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7760216)*" by Fujimoto, Fujisawa and Ikehara.

From the discrete Fourier transform of my two shifted images, I can according to the paper split up the phase component from the normalized cross power spectrum function R
$$
R(k_1,k_2) = \frac{F(k_1,k_2)G^*(k_1,k_2)}{|F(k_1,k_2)G^*(k_1,k_2)|} = e^{j\theta(k_1,k_2)}
$$
into two separate components (integer and decimal components). Given by:
$$
\theta(k_1,k_2) \approx ak_1+bk_2 = (a'+a'')k_1+(b'+b'')k_2
$$
Where a and b are the coefficients for the slope of the phase component of each direction k1 and k2. By subtracting the integer shift, I can then find the phase component (theta'') with only the decimal shift.
$$
\theta ''(k_1,k_2) = \theta(k_1,k_2)-(a'k_1+b'k_2) \approx a''k_1+b''k_2
$$
Here the slopes of the integer shift (a’ and b’) are according to the paper found by using the conventional phase only correlation (POC). However, I can’t seem to figure out how to get a’ and b’ from the conventional POC. I am able to find the integer shift in pixels, by finding the location of the max POC peak:

[image: Image of max POC peak]

But from my understanding the integer shift from the peak would be in the spatial domain, while a’ and b’ is the slope of the phase component of the integer shift and is defined in the frequency domain. As they are defined in two different domains I’m having a hard time understanding how I can obtain the slope values a' and b' from the integer shift that I have found using POC.

I’m therefore wondering if someone could help me understand how can I obtain the phase component of the integer shift, and how I can get the slopes a’ and b’ by using phase only correlation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!